# How do I extract and sort the instance variables of one class, that are stored in an array inside of an instance variable in another class using ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, instance, instance-variables

While learning more about Ruby, I'm currently running into a wall. I'm trying to extract and sort the value of an instance variable of one class, that's stored in an array inside an instance variable in another class. I seem to only be able to grab the instance of the class itself, rather than the specific instance variables within the class.

Below are the two classes.

**product.rb**

```
class Product
  attr_reader :name,
              :price

  def initialize(name, price)
    @name = name
    @price = price
  end
end
```

**catalogue.rb**

```
class Catalogue
  attr_reader :contents

  def initialize
    @contents = []
  end

  def cheapest
    @contents.product.first
  end

  def <<(product)
    @contents << product
  end
end
```

The following test confirms I'm not properly extracting and sorting `@name` nor `@price` for the instance of `Product` that's stored in `@contents` in the instance of `Catalogue`.

**catalogue_test.rb**

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'                                                             
require 'minitest/autorun'                                                           
require 'minitest/pride'  
require 'catalogue'
require 'product'

class CatalogueTest < Minitest::Test                                                 
  def test_cheapest_of_one                                                           
    catalogue = Catalogue.new                                                        
    catalogue << Product.new('scissors', 8)                                          
    assert_equal 'scissors', catalogue.cheapest                                      
  end                                                                          
end
```

Here is the failure:

```
Failure:
CatalogueTest#test_cheapest_of_one [catalogue_test.rb:16]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"scissors"
+[#<Product:0xXXXXXX @name="scissors", @price=8>]
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to extract and sort the product based on price across a number of instances. I realize I will need to further extend the existing code to ensure I'm grabbing the cheapest (when there is more than one object in the array), but was just trying to start with a basic function to access the elements in it.

Thus far I've tried some different methods like `sort` and `first`, however, I'm unable to go beyond the above output, `[#<Product:0xXXXXXX @name="scissors", @price=8>]`, and drill down into the instance variables. ‍♂️

What would I need to add to `catalogue.rb` to make `test_cheapest_of_one` in `catalogue_test.rb` pass?

Comment: In your test, you are testing whether a `Product` is equal to a `String`. Obviously, a `Product` will *never* be equal to a `String`. A `Product` will only be equal to a `Product` and a `String` will only be equal to a `String`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Yes, was thinking the `cheapest` method needs to be modified to grab 'scissors' out of `[#<Product:0xXXXXXX @name="scissors", @price=8>]`.

Comment: For clarity, you are attempting to use getter methods on an instance of a class, not trying to read its instance variables. If you were trying to read instance variables that would be an issue of improper encapsulation. Getter methods may choose to expose instance variables but do not have to.

Comment: @anothermh Thanks for clarifying. I'm not sure what methods I should be trying to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your test will work with the following method definition:

```
def cheapest
  @contents.sort_by(&:price).reverse.first.name
end
```

or alternatively

```
def cheapest
  @contents.sort_by { |product| produce.price * -1 }.first.name
end
```

Currently you're trying calling `@contents.product`, which is actually calling [Array#product](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/product) - not what you want.

Comment: @en1on glad it worked. You can alternatively use [max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) instead of `sort_by...first`

Answer (score 1):

In your question, you ask:

> What would I need to add to `catalogue.rb` to make `test_cheapest_of_one` in `catalogue_test.rb` pass?

But, that is the wrong question to ask! As I alluded to in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61356652/how-do-i-extract-and-sort-the-instance-variables-of-one-class-that-are-stored-i#comment108543475_61356652), your problem is that, **in your test**, you are testing whether a `Product` is equal to a `String`, which can *never* be `true`, because a Product will never be equal to a String. A Product will only be equal to a Product and a String will only be equal to a String.

So, the problem is *with your test*, not with the production code.

If you were to modify your production code, you would have to change the `cheapest` method to return the *name* of the cheapest product. But that is *wrong*. It should return the cheapest *product*. It doesn't help you if it returns the name, because there's nothing useful you can do with the name. You cannot print out how much the cheapest product costs, for example, because you don't know what the cheapest product is, you only know what it is called.

The correct solution is to modify the test, so that it tests that the correct product is returned, not the name:

```rb
def test_cheapest_of_one
  catalogue = Catalogue.new
  scissors  = Product.new('scissors', 8)
  catalogue << scissors

  assert_equal scissors, catalogue.cheapest
end
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.